# How to set SelectParameter in code behind in Asp.net web forms application?

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net, gridview, sqldatasource

I keep getting the error, Must declare the scalar variable "@inspIdFk" when attempting to use the following:

```
protected void rgInspections_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        foreach (GridDataItem item in rgInspections.SelectedItems)
        {
            hdn_insp_id_pk.Value = item["inspIdPk"].Text;
        }

        string inspidvalue = hdn_insp_id_pk.Value;

        if (HttpContext.Current.User.IsInRole("AKOB") || (HttpContext.Current.User.IsInRole("aMgr")))
        {
            SqlDataSource sdcRgActExps2 = new SqlDataSource();
            sdcRgActExps2.ID = "sdcRgActExps2";
            this.Page.Controls.Add(sdcRgActExps2);
            sdcRgActExps2.ConnectionString = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["DefaultConnection"].ConnectionString;
            sdcRgActExps2.SelectCommand = "SELECT ae.actExpIdPk, ae.inspIdFk, ae.actExpDt, aet.actExpType, ae.actExpQty, ae.actExpRate, ae.actExpBill, (ae.actExpQty * ae.actExpRate) AS subTotal FROM inspActExps ae LEFT JOIN actExpTypes aet ON ae.actExpType = aet.actExpTypeIdPk WHERE ([inspIdFk] = @inspIdFk) AND actExpSecCd = 1 ORDER BY actExpDt";
            sdcRgActExps2.SelectParameters.Add("@inspIdFk", inspidvalue);
            rgActExps2.DataSource = sdcRgActExps2;
            rgActExps2.DataBind();
        }
        else
        { 
            ...
        }
    }
```

How can I successfully set the value of @inspIdFk?  I verified that the query does pull data by removing inspIdFk = @inspIdFk from the WHERE clause.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I understand it, SqlDataSource.SelectParameters.Add takes a parameter name **without** an ampersand, so your add should look like this:

```
sdcRgActExps2.SelectParameters.Add("inspIdFk", inspidvalue);
```

Comment: Thank you for such a quick response.